# How to configure nexus maintenance tasks?

Tags: maven, nexus

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1650403/7581) has some nice tips about maintaining an internal maven repository, but it's rather vague on the details.
In particular, the answer says

> Configure Nexus to do the following for internal repos
>
> 1. Delete old Snapshots on regular intervals
> 2. Delete Snapshots on release

But I haven't figured out how to do that. Where in nexus configuration can I make these changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's described in the [Nexus book, "Managing Scheduled Tasks"](http://www.sonatype.com/books/nexus-book/reference/confignx-sect-managing-tasks.html).

Unfortunately it seems I cannot link directly to the description of the snapshot removal task. The section is called "Remove Snapshots from Repository".