# Looking for a demo project to present Maven

Tags: maven, presentation, demo

I'd like to introduce Maven to my fellow coworkers who mostly use Ant to build their projects.

One of my goal would be to show them the benefit of building a corporate repository to easily share reusable components. But first of all, I need to show them the basics.

I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3883827/need-presentation-materials-for-convincing-a-customer-to-use-maven) about presentation materials with a very good answer from Pascal. But I really need a demo project to actually show Maven in action, some sort of toy project, simple but complete enough to illustrate the basics (dependency management, multiple modules, unit testing, profiles, ...).

All what I have so far is a real life project which looks too complicated and noisy to focus on the basics.

I don't expect something complete and I'm ready to modify it to fit my needs. Anything preventing me to start from scratch would be helpful. Please note that I'd be happy to share whatever work I have to do to build this demo.

Comment: Since they already use Ant have you considered introducing `Ivy`?  Which as I recall is the other paradigm `Ant + Ivy` instead of `Maven`

Comment: @Woot4Moot thanks for the tip. As I've never used Ivy myself it will be hard for me to present it. However I'll definitely mention it in my presentation as an alternative so people can make their own investigation and choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is [A Simple Maven Project](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnex-book/reference/simple-project.html) from sonatype.

[Netbeans.org](http://netbeans.org) provides two tutorials for Maven:

- [Creating a Maven Swing Application Using Hibernate](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/maven-hib-java-se.html)
- [Creating an Enterprise Application Using Maven](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/maven-entapp.html)

Comment: Thanks. there was some delay but I'm finally starting preparing this presentation and using the sample project.

Answer (score 1):

You can choose from [archetype list](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Archetypes+List) or you can find one for your favorite technology, e.g. [gwt](http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/user-guide/archetype.html).

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about archetypes. Very helpful. I'll take a look there.