# Where should I store the SVG for icons in android app repository?

Tags: android, repository

I'm developing an Android app and storing all the relevant files in a git repository.

Now, I created an icon in SVG and exported it into several PNG. As usual, I placed the PNG in the relevant res/drawable directories.

The question is where should I store the SVG? It should not be contained in the resulting apk (therefore it's not an asset).

I'm thinking about a folder named `media` that would contain SVGs and possibly other outputs. Like:

```
media/
media/res/drawables/
    ic_launcher.svg
media/apk/
    app-1.0.apk    (signed apks)
    app-1.1.apk
media/screenshot/
    screen1.png    (screenshots published in a store)
    screen2.png
```

Is this a correct approach?

Where exactly should the `media` folder be located? What is the usual naming convention?

Comment: You can use svg's directly with latest development tools.

Comment: OK. And what about the other content like apks and screenshots? Where do they go?

Comment: Usually people use some sort of build artifact repository. See here for some recommendations: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11437695/1615903