# Best Repository Management for Maven

Tags: maven, jenkins, maven-plugin, maven-release-plugin, binary-repository

I am working on Automated Build using  maven and Jenkins. I am looking for best open source  Repository Management for Maven. So that I can have an integaration between Maven and jenkins via respository manager.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have at least four choices:

- [Nexus](http://nexus.sonatype.org/)
- [Artifactory](http://www.jfrog.com/products.php)
- [Apache Archiva](http://archiva.apache.org/)
- [Reposilite](https://reposilite.com/)

Each has pros and cons. I'd go with Nexus since it is backed by Sonatype who are also involved in Maven development. I liked the Artifactory UI though.
Both Nexus and Artifactory have supported professional editions as well.

These are linked from the [maven site](http://maven.apache.org/repository-management.html) as well.

Comment: That was really cool  Thanks for the links <Feature Matrix>, I was really in need of this comparision.Thanks a lot raguram

Comment: All Codehaus services have now been terminated.
See http://www.codehaus.org/ for details.
A copy of the "Feature Matrix" can now be found here: http://binary-repositories-comparison.github.io/

Comment: The Matrix link from above is obsolete for today, but valuable real discussion  can be found at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364775/should-we-use-nexus-or-artifactory-for-a-maven-repo