# Archiva vs Artifactory

Tags: maven, artifactory, archiva

What's the difference between Archiva vs Artifactory repository for MAVEN ?

Anybody has comparison chart on this ?

Which one is better out of these 2 as i am looking for free repository not looking for license version so i know NEXUS is best but don't consider as discussion point here on that.

Comment: Possibly related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8411297/best-repository-management-for-maven

Comment: Also keep in mind that Nexus Open Source is completely free to use as well so it is an option for you.