# Github un-ignore a file when tagging

Tags: git

I have a git repository where the compiled version of my project is ignored in `.gitignore`.

When I release a new version of my project (tag the `master` branch to the version) I want to commit the compiled files, but then revert back to ignoring them.

is this possible? I would like to avoid committing a new version of my .gitignore every time I release a new version.

Answer (score 0):

You can do `git commit -f file-in-gitignore` (probably also `git add -f file-in-gitignore`). In general, it is a bad idea to include generated files, perhaps open a branch just for those files, or distribute them somewhere else?

Comment: but using git add -f then I'll need to remove them after I've tagged the new version... Yes and I'd like to avoid using generated files but I need them, at least when publishing a new version

Comment: @MatteoPagliazzi, no way around that I can see

Answer (score 0):

> When I release a new version of my project (tag the master branch to the version) I want to commit the compiled files

Why not.
I would simply recommend not doing it in the same referential.

A *source* version control system will retain the *history* of what you are putting inside, and binaries don't diff well, consuming space quickly.

An [artifact repository](http://www.sonatype.com/people/2009/04/what-is-a-repository/) ([like Nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/), or [other alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364775/should-we-use-nexus-or-artifactory-for-a-maven-repo)) is much more suited for that kind of release (for binaries or any kind of *generated* files), the idea being that you can very easily purge old releases from the referential (a simple flat files-based system).

Don't forget to include in your release a file text *declaring* the SHA1 or your source repo, in order to keep a link between the exact revision of your sources from which you produced said binaries.